# how to highlight target node while dragging

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a treeview and trying to move node to parent node(drag and drop),

Is there any way that allows targeted node to show a backcolor while mouse over(left button is still hold with an item dragged)?

[Update]
how come following code not work ??

```
    private TreeNode nodeOver=null;
    private void treeView_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
       Point p = treeView.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
       nodeOver = treeView.GetNodeAt(p.X, p.Y);
        nodeOver.BackColor = Color.Aquamarine;
    }
    private void treeView_DragLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        nodeOver.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
```

Comment: it's hard to identify target node while moving

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
    private void treeView_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        ClearBackground(treeView.Nodes);
        Point p = treeView.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        TreeNode node = treeView.GetNodeAt(p.X, p.Y);
        node.BackColor = Color.Aquamarine;
    }

    private void ClearBackground(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
        {
            node.BackColor = Color.White;
            ClearBackground(node.Nodes);
        }
    }
```

**Edit**

Here's an improved version that shouldn't cause flickering:

```
    private void treeView_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Point p = treeView.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        TreeNode node = treeView.GetNodeAt(p.X, p.Y);
        if (node.PrevVisibleNode != null)
        {
            node.PrevVisibleNode.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
        if (node.NextVisibleNode != null)
        {
            node.NextVisibleNode.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
        node.BackColor = Color.Aquamarine;
    }
```

Comment: if the height of the treeview items are constant, you can probably drop the recursive ClearBackground method and only change the background color of the items above and below the current item back to white

Comment: Or better yet, just use node.NextVisibleNode & node.PrevVisibleNode and revert their background colors if not null

Comment: great the improved version works much better, thanks a lot for the help

Comment: I prefer this solution because highlight both selected and destination node, but it need the following improvement to manage exception of null node  TreeNode _oldnode;
        private void Tree_DragOver....
        {
            if (node != null)
            {
                if (node.PrevVisibleNode != null)
                ..................
                node.BackColor = Color.Red;
                _oldnode = node;
            }
            else
            {
                if (_oldnode != null)
                    _oldnode.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
        }

Answer (score 5):

Veldmius, your answer above is unreliable and a little verbose. If there is no previous or next node available, then NextVisibleNode and PreviousVisibleNode throw null exceptions.

The way I would do it is as follows... 
Go to the properties of the treeview in designer. 
Set HideSelection = False

Then wire up the dragover event with these 2 lines of code.

```
private void treeview1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode node = treeview1.GetNodeAt(treeview1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y)));
        treeview1.SelectedNode = node;
    }
```